# Windows Forms half-pie chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Is it possible to create pie chart that is not full disc using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`?

**Edit**

Like this:

[image]

I don't get how my question is "to broad". What could I add more? It's very specific question about a single component and TaW answered it nicely in the comment.

Here is his hack:

```
chart1.Titles.Add("Pie Chart");
chart1.Series["s1"].Points.AddXY("A", 33);
chart1.Series["s1"].Points.AddXY("B", 35);
chart1.Series["s1"].Points.AddXY("C", 36);
chart1.Series["s1"].Points.Insert(
    0, new DataPoint(0, 33 + 35 + 36) {
        Color = Color.Transparent,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
    }
);
var ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ca.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 200);
```

Though I don't quite understand the `InnerPlotPosition` part.
Please post this as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Did you try ? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is supported but you can try a workaround by starting with an empty half circle. Add this after adding your points to your `Series s`: `s.Points.Insert(0, new DataPoint(0, s.Points.Sum(x => x.YValues[0]))
            { Color = Color.Transparent, IsVisibleInLegend = false });` - To make it fill the chartarea use this `ChartArea ca = chart4.ChartAreas[0];
            ca.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 200);` - This will also work for doughnut charts. Note that some calulations will now have to in/exlude the extra point. So percentages should be doubled etc

Comment: Did this help??